# Is there any advantage to Rsync moving files on the same machine?

Tags: bash, files, rsync, mv

I was reading [how to install Magento on Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04). All files are on the server. the author says:

> We will use `rsync` to transfer our Magento files there, since `rsync`
>   will include important hidden files like `.htaccess`. Once the transfer
>   is complete, we can clean up our home directory by deleting the
>   `magento` folder and archive there.
>
> ```
> sudo rsync -avP ~/magento/. /var/www/html/
> ```
>
> `rsync` will safely copy all of the contents from the directory that you
>   unpacked to the document root at `/var/www/html/`.

i've been using Linux for a long long time and never used Rsync to move files on the same machine, and never encoutered the problems mentioned by the author. Digital Ocean hires professional authors so there might be a point behind his claims.

Is there an advantage to using Rsync over mv or cp, when moving files on the same machine?

Comment: Really no advantage for the same system, but that's a good backup tool. It has more sophisticated options than mv, and plus mv often needs to be interfaced with find or some other command set

Comment: What author also mentioned is the hidden files. If you move folders with mv, they will preserve hidden files. But again, to be sure, id use find command in conjunction with mv, since find does show hidden files

Comment: @Serg mv always move hidden files in my experience, ive never faced a situation where hidden files wen missing, is it poosible?

Comment: possible if you do something like mv * . Do for example `echo * | grep bashrc` in your home folder.  If you move directory that's fine , like `mv ~/bin ~/new-bin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the point is to transfer the content of `magento` to `/var/www/html`. That's to say, if we had:

```
magento
├── .bar
└── foo
```

We'd get:

```
html
├── .bar
└── foo
```

This is annoying, but not difficult, to accomplish this with `mv`. You'd have to use some form of `find`, or enable `dotglob` in bash, to include the `.bar`.

`rsync` is simpler.

With `find`:

```
find magento -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t /var/www/html {} +
```

With `dotglob` in bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv magento/* /var/www/html
```

Comment: wouldnt cd into the folder and mv * have the same effect?

Comment: @Lynob `*` doesn't include files or folders beginning with `.` by default.

Comment: aghhhhhhhhhhh i see

Comment: strange, i dont recall having this problem before